# Nethereum: CallAsync return a wrong msg.sender

Tags: addresses, nethereum

I write this simple contract:

```
contract greeter {
    event LogSender(address sender);
    function getSender() constant returns (address) {
       LogSender(msg.sender);
       return msg.sender;
   }
}
```

### Web Env [OK]

1. Google Chrome with MetaMask Plugin
2. Remix for Compile, Deploy and Run My contract
3. Geth client in private test network

I choose account in MetaMask, call the function getSender() and it return the right value (the selected address in MetaMask)

### C# Env (Nethereum) [WRONG]

1. Windows Form app with included Nethereum Portable Lib
2. Geth client in private test network

   ```
   try
   {
       Web3 web3 = new Web3(new ManagedAccount(txtAddress.Text, txtPassword.Text), "http://localhost:8545");

       GreeterService gs = new GreeterService(web3, txtContractAddress.Text);

       var res = await gs.GetSenderAsyncCall();

       txtLog.AppendText("getSender: " + res + "\n");
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       txtLog.AppendText(ex.Message + "\n");
   }
   ```

When I call the function with C#, res => first address of geth accounts! The address used for create an instance of ManagedAccount is not recognized!

Please give me support guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the wallet address in if you want specific info on a specirfic address

```
    Contracts.Function myFunctionName = contract.GetFunction("YourFunctionName");
    bool value = await myFunctionName.CallAsync<bool>(from: address, gas: new HexBigInteger(0), value: new HexBigInteger(0), functionInput: i);
```

This assumes you have a function that checks the wallet address for something based on i as an index (returning true or false);

There is no gas cost for checking information from the Blockchain.

Comment: Even if the gas won't be charged this call will fail, if the gas parameter is set to 0. We need to pass the EstimateGasAsync result called from function instance